# Does GLSL support C-style initializers or not?

Tags: opengl, glsl

From the OpenGL Wiki page on "[Data Type (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Struct_constructors)", I found a pretty broad statement about initializer lists.

> ...Therefore, GLSL takes a feature from C++11 and allows the
>   initialization of **any type** by using an initializer list. An
>   initializer list is a list of initializers (which themselves could be
>   initializer lists) that are used to initialize a variable. Initializer
>   lists are bounded by curly braces ("{" and "}").
>
> Initializer lists **do not require specifying the type name**; the
>   compiler will deduce it correctly. And this deduction extends down the
>   hierarchy of objects in aggregates (structs/arrays). For example, the
>   above code could be initialized with the following initializer list:
>
> Data dataArray[3] = { {...}, ... }

I have tried a number of variations on initializer lists, and I'm not convinced.

```
# version 330
vec4 by_return(void) { return {1.0}; } // unexpected '{', expecting "::"
vec4 by_decl(void) { vec4 x = {1}; return x; } // too little data in initialization
```

Okay, initializer lists are not equivalent to constructors of the deduced type, e.g. `vec4(1.0)`...

```
vec4 by_decl(void) { vec4 x = {1,0,0,0}; return x; }
// OpenGL does not allow C style initializers
```

...but it's moot. Just in case "any type" was more broad than intended, I made sure to try a variant where a struct should be deduced in an outer initializer list, and another with an explicit constructor but arguments given as initializer lists:

```
struct Dual { vec4 u, v; }
Dual struct_outer(void) { return {vec4(1,0,0,0), vec4(0,0,0,0)}; } // unexpected '{', expecting "::"
Dual struct_inner(void) { return Dual({1,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}); } // unexpected '{', expecting "::"
```

Contrast that result with the next few lines of the Wiki:

> The compiler automatically deduces that the second element of each
>   Data member is an vec2. This is based on the definition of Data.

Finally, arrays should be no different from structs, so this should come as no surprise:

```
vec4[2] as_array(void) { return {{1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}}; } // unexpected '{', expecting "::"
vec4[2] as_array2(void) { vec4 x[2] = {{1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}}; return x; }
//    OpenGL does not allow C style initializers
vec4[2] as_array3(void) { return {vec4(1), vec4(1)}; } // unexpected '{', expecting "::"
vec4[2] as_array4(void) { return vec4[2]{vec4(1), vec4(1)}; } // unexpected '{', expecting "::"
vec4[2] as_array5(void) { vec4[2] x; x[0] = {1,0,0,0}; x[1] = {0,0,0,0}; return x; } // unexpected '{', expecting "::"
```

From everything I've seen so far, it looks the compiler is capable of parsing a "C style initializer", but only in assignment, and for the sole purpose of rejecting it more explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initializer lists are a later addition to OpenGL. The Wiki notes off to the side that this feature is "core since version 4.2". I made sure to include my `#version 330` statement because I was so sure that initializer lists were an earlier addition than GL 3.3, and I didn't even question that until the moment I was about to submit the question. Lesson learned, I think.